# array length in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var a = [1,4,5];
var e = a.length--;
```

Here `e` variable will contain 5. But if I do:

```
var e = a.length-=1;
```

Here `e` will contain 2 the number of elements array.

So the first is a language 'tip' to simulate a pop() array methods?

In the language syntax doing:

```
a--
```

or

```
a-=1
```

is semantically the same.

Comment: Where is the question in your post ?

Comment: So the first is a language 'tip' to simulate a pop() array methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var a = [1, 4, 5];
var e = a.length--;
```

is the same as

```
var a = [1, 4, 5];
var e = a.length;
a.length = a.length - 1;
```

whereas

```
 var a = [1, 4, 5];
 var e = a.length -= 1;
```

is the same as

```
var a = [1, 4, 5];
a.length = a.length - 1;
var e = a.length;
```

and

```
var a = [1, 4, 5];
var e = --a.length;
```

In other words: x-- returns the value before decreasing whereas --x (and x -= 1) returns the value after decreasing. All these code snippets pop the last element off the array a.

Note that in the first example, `e = a.length--`, e will have the value 3, not 5, therefore it is *not* the same as `a.pop()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic misconception: If you evaluate `a++`, a will be evaluated and *then* incremented while `++a` or `a+=1` will be incremented first, then evaluated.

In most cases it's better to write these kinds of statements in a more verbose manner because they can quickly lead to confusion about what is going on while not gaining anything (most compilers / interpreters will optimize this anyway).

Answer (score 1):

That's not what I get.

Rather, I get the expected result. e = 3 in the first instance, and e = 2 in the second.

In the first case, a.length is initially 3 (because javascript arrays are sparse). using the post-decrement, this value (3) is first assigned to e, then a.length is decremented (funny this is possible, actually).

In the second case, 1 is subtracted from 3 to make 2, which is then assigned to e.

So I don't think there's anything fancy going on, really.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [1,4,5];
var e = a.length--;
```

e will not contain 5. It will contain 3.

The -- postix decrement operator will make no difference here. `a.length` is 3. The second statement translates as:

- retrieve array length  (result: 3)
- store result in variable named "e"
- decrement array length (this step has no effect on the overall outcome for this standalone sample)

Whereas:

```
var a = [1,4,5];
var e = a.length-=1;
```

here e *will* contain 2.

The second statement translates as

- retrieve array length (result: 3)
- decrement array length (result: 2)
- store result in variable named "e"

In any case, you are messing with the `array.length` property, which you shouldn't do. It causes the kind of nasty bug that is hard to track down because it is result of a side effect you probably did not intend or think of.

Answer (score 0):

oh yes I read this from the book : Object Oriented Javascript at page 112

> > > The push() method appends a new element at the end of the array. The pop() method removes the last element. a.push('new') works just like a[a.length] = 'new' and a.pop() is the same as a.length--.

and without try the code I post the question!!!

Sorry. So I think this is a book error because pop() returns the last element where
a.length-- shrink the array but not returning the element but the array lenght -1