# Decrement array length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, decrement

I just ran across this javascript snippet:

```
myArray.length--;
```

What does it do exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626500/array-length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This removes the last items in the array.

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
myArray.length--;
alert(myArray);
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: interesting does not know that!

Answer (score 3):

Simple experimentation shows that it chops off last element of the array.

```
> var a = [1, 2, 3];
=> undefined
> a
=> [1, 2, 3]
> a.length--
=> 3
> a
=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: What do you use for an interpreter?  I've never seen an interactive javascript console like that.

Comment: Chrome's javascript console :-)

Comment: Which by the way you get to by pressing F12, then clicking the >= toolbar icon on the very bottom. That and other features in chrome even allow you to experiment and alter the current page. (The other browsers offer some versions of this feature - also try the jsFiddle website)